# Cross Browser, Object Persistence Library for Client Application

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, hta, object-persistence

I'm creating a client based application in [HTML Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536496%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (HTA) and I would like to know if there's a object persistent library similar to python's [shevle](http://docs.python.org/library/shelve.html) that meets the following criteria:

- Should be able to read and write on file
- Cross browser: should work at least on both HTA and on Firefox (through XULRunner) so that I'll be not tied to any vendor.
- Written in JavaScript form

[TiddyWiki](http://www.tiddlywiki.com/) is able to save itself, regardless of the browser used, though the codes that saves and retrieves files has to be refactored to meet my need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I wasn't aware that TiddyWiki has a [github](https://github.com/TiddlyWiki/tiddlywiki) repository, and they organized the files by [module](https://github.com/TiddlyWiki/tiddlywiki/tree/master/js).

I could just take the `FileSystem.js` file and build a nice api on top of it to simulate `shelve` functionality.